# Scala type bounds "single-levelness"

Tags: scala, type-bounds

Let's have a hierarchy defined like this:

```
trait Upper
case class Error(msg: String) extends Upper
```

Trying to define a trait like this:

```
trait Mixin[T <: Upper] {

  def compute[S <: T](param: String, obj: S)

  def use = compute("hello", Error("world"))

}
```

Causes compilation error:

```
error: inferred type arguments [Error] do not conform to method compute's type parameter bounds [S <: T]
             def use = compute("hello", Error("world"))
                       ^
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Error
 required: S
             def use = compute("hello", Error("world"))
                                             ^
```

Can someone explain me why that happens, and how to workaround it?

**Update**

The type bounds can't be removed. They are necessary because of some implicits that won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this, but the type parameter `T` on `Mixin` is an invariant with an upper-bound of `Upper`. That means that we know it is *some* sub-type of `Upper`, but we don't know *which*--which means we *don't* know that it has type `Error`. And we can't know that `Error` is a sub-type of `T`.

If you introduce a third type `case class A extends Upper`, it becomes more clear why this can't work.

`T` might be `A`, and if `S <: A`, then `S = Error <: T = A` is impossible.

How can you work around this? Remove the type bounds. It's not clear why you have them in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense. I can't remove the type bounds on compute, but I'm trying to make it more generic. The body of compute needs the type bounds to use some implicits. Namely they are `spray` marshallers, and the `compute` function is my version of `complete` that has to marshall `obj` into JSON, HTML, etc. depending on the upper bound type.